# A deleted image filename is printed to the top of SOME of my nodes

Tags: files

### Background:

I once had an image file in the site (I think the image was added via an image-field I already deleted).

### The problem:

This image filename I described is printed to the top of **SOME** of my nodes (I should note that these are nodes from different content-types). In some nodes it doesn't appear but in some others it does... Any idea why would this strange beahvior happen?

- I already tried to flush all caches - didn't help.

### Live examples (Images):

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't know the mechanism of the behavior, deleting the SQL file-data from the relevant SQL tables via PHPmyAdmin **and then** flushing all caches, solved the problem.

Note: There where references to the file in 2 tables (One table deals with files and one deals with the Watchdog).